# Обернуть выражение в функцию

Tags: c++

Имеется класс:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int MyFunc(int, bool);
};
```

Получаю адрес своего метода класса из другой части программы:

```
typedef int (MyClass::* pToFunc)(int, bool);
pToFunc ptf = &MyClass::MyFunc;
LPVOID adr = (LPVOID&)ptf;
```

или

```
int(MyClass::*pFn)(int, bool) = &MyClass::MyFunc;
LPVOID adr = (LPVOID&)pFn;
```

Возможно ли выражение получения адреса добавить в отдельную функцию или обернуть в макрос? т.е. что-то вроде:

```
LPVOID GetAddr(......)
......................
LPVOID adr = GetAddr(MyClass::MyFunc);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение получения адреса можно обернуть в макрос:

```
#define GetAddr1(ClassName, Method) &ClassName::Method

pToFunc ptf = GetAddr1(MyClass, MyFunc);
```

или

```
#define GetAddr2(Method) &Method

pToFunc ptf = GetAddr1(MyClass::MyFunc);
```

Но приводить указатель на (нестатический) метод класса к `LPVOID` (`void*`) нельзя, поскольку, как верно заметил @Abyx, "указатели на методы - это не указатели".

Comment: В `c++` нет методов, есть функции-члены, и следовательно "указатели на члены".

Comment: @alexolut ... и есть устоявшееся и часто используемое, хоть и не соответствующее стандарту, их альтернативное название *"методы"*.